# Python find all the words with less than 5 letters in the string in a given text

Tags: python, list

This code doesn't work right now because I don't know the exact code I should use. I need to print out the number of words containing less than 5 letters.
This is what I've been trying:

```
text = "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout."
words = text.split()
letterCount = {w: len(w) for w in words}

lessthan5 = '1,2,3,4'
count = 0
if words == lessthan5 :      #i put words to refer to line 3(letter count)
     result = count + 1
     print(result)
```

The output I need is an integer, ex.17.
Pls help thank u so much

Comment: `sum([1 for i in text.split() if len(i)<5])`

Comment: You don't really need the `if`clause; you can just sum the boolean: `sum(len(word) < 5 for word in words)`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
text = "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout."
words = text.split()
count = 0
for word in words:
    if len(word) < 5:
        count = count + 1

print(count)
```

Comment: @Ruby You welcome, don't forget to upvote and/or accept as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one simple solution using a regular expression. The advantage of using a regular expression rather than just splitting the input at whitespace is that you can more precisely define what a "word" is. For example, you can exclude punctuation, so that `"a full stop."` counts as three words less than five characters long. (With `str.split` and a filter on string length, the last word would be `"stop."` instead of `"stop"`, so it wouldn't show up, leaving only two words.)

```py
>>> import re
>>> rg = re.compile(r"\b\w{1,4}\b")
```

The above regular expression means "starting at a word boundary, followed by from one to four word characters followed by a word boundary.

```py
>>> text = ("It is a long established fact that a reader"
            " will be distracted by the readable content"
            " of a page when looking at its layout.")
>>> rg.findall(text)
['It', 'is', 'a', 'long', 'fact', 'that', 'a', 'will', 'be', 'by', 'the', 'of', 'a', 'page', 'when', 'at', 'its']
>>> len(rg.findall(text)
17
```

`re.findall`, as its name indicates, finds all of the instances of a regular pattern in a string, returning the matches in a vector.